# Blanking second end after blanking the first

Tags: strategy, curling

In curling it is advantageous to blank the first end, resulting in a presumable advantage in the remaining odd number of ends.  Do I blank the 2nd end?

Answer (score 3):

(I assume you mean that you have started with the hammer).  Blanking the first *only* because of the odd number of remaining ends in regulation does not seem a good decision.  You're giving up potential points that you can't get back.  It doesn't take much to have a bad end with your opponents stealing and then you're back with the hammer in an odd end.  I certainly am not starting the first end planning to blank it (which is how your question reads).

Instead, I think of having the hammer as giving an expected score in the end greater than 1.  If all the guards are gone and we think we will not be able to score multiple points, then we'll consider if blanking is possible, *because I want to maximize the points scored with the hammer*.

Early in the match, I wouldn't care overmuch about which end it is, so blanking 1, 2, or 3 doesn't matter too much.  Later in the match it depends on the score and then keeping the hammer in the even ends is more important.

Given that, nothing ties the first and the second ends together in my mind.  I don't care if the first end was a blank with my hammer or if the opponents scored or what.  With hammer in the second end, I'm looking to score multiple points, and would consider keeping it blank if that becomes unlikely.